# Spark AccumulatorV2 with HashMap

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to create a custom AccumulatorV2 with a hash map, the input would be hashmap and output would be a map of HashMap,

My intention is to have a K -> K1,V, where the value will increment. I am confused by the scala syntax for overriding AccumulatorV2 for Map, did anyone had a luck with this.

```
class CustomAccumulator extends AccumulatorV2[java.util.Map[String, String], java.util.Map[String,java.util.Map[String, Double]]]
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? I don't see anything wrong with the class signature.

Comment: I know the class signature is correct, what I am after is the unimplemented override methods that need to be implemented, there are 6 of them to be implemented, for example this one  def merge(other: org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2[java.util.Map[String,String],java.util.Map[String,java.util.Map[String,Double]]]): Unit = ??? , how to overide the merge method

Comment: I don't understand your question. You are trying to understand how to implement an AccumulatorV2 ?

Comment: @eliasah, how to implement a accumulatorv2 that take a map containing another map and return a map containing another map. I need to increment the value part of the inner map. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is the scenario that needs to be implemented.

**Input:**
HashMap<String, String>

**Output:**

Should output a HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>>, where the second hashmap contains the count of values corresponding to the keys.

**Example:**

**Inputs:***(Following HashMaps are added to the accumulator)*

```
Input HashMap1 -> {"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "value1"}, {"key3", "value3"}
Input HashMap2 -> {"key1", "value1"}, {"key2", "value1"}
Input HashMap3 -> {"key2", "value1"}
```

Output:

```
{"key1", {"value1", 2}}, {"key2", {"value1", 3}}, {"key3", {"value3", 1}}
```

Code below:

```
import java.util
import java.util.Map.Entry
import java.util.{HashMap, Map}
import java.util.function.{BiFunction, Consumer}

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2
import org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.fieldmanager.OldValueParameterSetter

class CustomAccumulator extends AccumulatorV2[Map[String, String], Map[String, Map[String,Double]]] {

  private var hashmap : Map[String, Map[String, Double]] = new HashMap[String, Map[String, Double]];

  override def isZero: Boolean = {
      return hashmap.size() == 0
  }

  override def copy(): AccumulatorV2[util.Map[String, String], util.Map[String, util.Map[String, Double]]] = {
    var customAccumulatorcopy = new CustomAccumulator()
    customAccumulatorcopy.merge(this)
    return customAccumulatorcopy
  }

  override def reset(): Unit = {
    this.hashmap = new HashMap[String, Map[String, Double]];
  }

  override def add(v: util.Map[String, String]): Unit = {
    v.foreach(kv => {
    val unitValueDouble : Double = 1;
      if(this.hashmap.containsKey(kv._1)){
        val innerMap = this.hashmap.get(kv._1)
        innerMap.merge(kv._2, unitValueDouble, addFunction)
      }
      else {
        val innerMap : Map[String, Double] = new HashMap[String, Double]()
        innerMap.put(kv._2, unitValueDouble)
        this.hashmap.put(kv._1, innerMap)
      }
    }
    )
  }

  override def merge(otherAccumulator: AccumulatorV2[util.Map[String, String], util.Map[String, util.Map[String, Double]]]): Unit = {
    otherAccumulator.value.foreach(kv => {
      this.hashmap.merge(kv._1, kv._2, mergeMapsFunction)
    })
  }

  override def value: util.Map[String, util.Map[String, Double]] = {
    return this.hashmap
  }

  val mergeMapsFunction = new BiFunction[Map[String, Double], Map[String, Double], Map[String, Double]] {
    override def apply(oldMap: Map[String, Double], newMap: Map[String, Double]): Map[String, Double] = {
      newMap.foreach(kv => {
        oldMap.merge(kv._1, kv._2, addFunction);
      })
      oldMap
    }
  }

  val addFunction =  new BiFunction[Double, Double, Double] {
    override def apply(oldValue: Double, newValue: Double): Double = oldValue + newValue
  }
}
```

Thanks!!!